# Не открывается сайт в питоне

Tags: python, selenium

Почему не открывается сайт http://download.geofabrik.de/ в питоне?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
driver.get("http://download.geofabrik.de/")
```

Я запускаю этот код, но открывает только главную страницу гугла, а не нужный мне сайт

Answer (score 2):

webbrowser.get(using='google-chrome').open_new_tab('http://download.geofabrik.de/')

Открывает ссылку через ваш браузер

Answer (score 1):

Потому что нужно использовать не  браузер Chrome, а специальный chromedriver.

Comment: А подскажите, пожалуйста, как потом нажать на какую-нибудь кнопку на этом сайте или на любом другом?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте это! Поможет. Тут `ChromeDriverManager().install()` сразу скачает нужный для вас драйвер и запустит с него и не надо указывать путь до драйвера

```
from selenium import webdriver

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver.get("http://download.geofabrik.de/")
        driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: чтобы работать с кнопками или другими элементами почитайте документацию) (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/click-element-method-selenium-python/) там всё подробно описано